# Adding an IP based flow entry using RYU REST API

Tags: rest, openflow, ryu

I am trying to add a flow entry using 
RYU OFCTL REST based api (ryu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app/ofctl_rest.html) for adding flows to an OVS Switch running on mininet

RYU is running **ofctl_rest** and **simple_switch** these two applications

I am using a simple topology with one switch 3 hosts ... 
h1 = 10.0.0.1

h2 = 10.0.0.2

h3 = 10.0.0.3

How do i add a flow entry to block all incoming packets from host h1.
I used a json object

```
data={
  "dpid": 1,
  "cookie": 2802,
  "priority": 3000,
  "match":{
   "nw_src": "10.0.0.1",
  },
  "actions": [ ]
}
```

But this flow entry is blocking all the pings from all the machines ...

can someone suggest how to add and IP address filtering rule in OVS using API

Answer (score 1):

I tried same thing and used the command below:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 100,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{
        "nw_src": "10.0.0.1",
         "dl_type": 2048
    },
    "actions":[
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add
```

Result is ok.

```
mininet> dpctl dump-flows
*** s1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=6.722s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=6, priority=100,ip,nw_src=10.0.0.1 actions=drop
...
```

After inserting this rule:

```
mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1000ms

mininet> h2 ping h3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.147 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
```

I've used ofctl_rest app for this setup and first insert all necessary rules to make host reachable each other. Here is the script for inserting those rules:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 0,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{},
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":"OUTPUT",
            "port": "CONTROLLER"
        }
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add


  curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 1,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{
        "in_port":2,
                "dl_dst":"00:00:00:00:00:01"
    },
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":"OUTPUT",
            "port": 1
        }
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add


curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 1,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{
        "in_port":1,
                "dl_dst":"00:00:00:00:00:02"
    },
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":"OUTPUT",
            "port": 2
        }
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add


curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 1,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{
        "in_port":3,
                "dl_dst":"00:00:00:00:00:01"
    },
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":"OUTPUT",
            "port": 1
        }
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add


curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 1,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{
        "in_port":1,
                "dl_dst":"00:00:00:00:00:03"
    },
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":"OUTPUT",
            "port": 3
        }
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add



 curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 1,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{
        "in_port":3,
                "dl_dst":"00:00:00:00:00:02"
    },
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":"OUTPUT",
            "port": 2
        }
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add


 curl -X POST -d '{
    "dpid": 1,
    "cookie": 0,
    "table_id": 0,
    "priority": 1,
    "flags": 1,
    "match":{
        "in_port":2,
                "dl_dst":"00:00:00:00:00:03"
    },
    "actions":[
        {
            "type":"OUTPUT",
            "port": 3
        }
    ]
 }' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution i shall try using this request instead of RYU ofctl  API... When you say insert all necessary rules

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution i shall try using this request instead of RYU ofctl  API... When you say insert all necessary rules are they not added when i use pingall command ? or there are some different set of rules that i need to add .... please help with this query ... also please do share all commands about ryu mininet and commands for adding flows

Comment: I've edited my answer and added the script I used. Ofctl_rest comes with no rules. You can add rules with the script I added. After that, pingall is ok. Then you can add drop action rule.