# Mininet: How to run controller code without using xterm

Tags: mininet, ryu

I have installed mininet on remote server, There is no X server installed in this machine. I am not able to run `xterm c0` command. gives error `Error: Cannot connect to display`

I want to run tests on switches using ryu. I am not able to open the controller in mininet and execute. Is there any alternative to `xterm` in mininet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need xterm if you need complex debugging as it is written in [Mininet documentation.](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#xterm-display)

> For more complex debugging, you can start Mininet so that it spawns
>   one or more xterms.

You can do lots of tests without xterm. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185910/adding-an-ip-based-flow-entry-using-ryu-rest-api/45329834#45329834) is an example of adding flows to mininet switches controlled by RYU.

[Mininet Walkthrough](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/) page also explains other tests that don't need xterm.